# In SSRS how to Disable future dates after today in the date picker calendar

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Could someone please help me out in this, on how do i freeze the future dates than the current date in the date picker calendar in SSRS date parameter.

Answer (score 0):

By default, there is no way to disable the future dates for the Date pick calendar in SQL server reporting services. But, you can do something to validate the date parameter value before report rendered, if the date value beyonds now, a message is shown to prompt the users the date entered invalidated, otherwise, the report works normally based on the date parameter selected.

Read this thread http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/8736ed6d-27f8-49ce-bbfa-718f4f4daa45/ for some workarounds to achieve this.I recommad the 1st one of the ways provided by Lukasz Pawlowski. Please don't use the messbox way, which desn't work in web due to it is only supported in window form platform.